# Running an std::async in a loop. How to get consistent results?

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11, parallel-processing, stdasync

I try to parallelize calculations and write the results in order to a vector.

I'm using a `std::async`. The program works perfectly with a short pause (ref. the commented line). Without this pause, the program crashes.

[The Code *<sub>( in an online IDE to modify & test the MCVE</sub>* :](https://godbolt.org/z/vs8n3j)

```
class AsyncDispatcher {
 public:
  /* Data is a custom class with data that contains a ID.
   * The object contains no
   * links or pointers.*/
  vector<Data> calcResult(vector<Params> params) {
    vector<Data> result;
    vector<std::future<NumberedData>> futures;

    threadID = 0;
    for (auto param : params) {
      futures.push_back(((std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));  // not workable without this command 
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return NumberedData(filler.createData(param, threadID), threadID);
      }))));
      threadID++;
    }

    for (auto& f : futures) {
      result.push_back(f.get().data);
    }
    return result;
  }

  AsyncDispatcher() : threadID(0) {}

 private:
  int threadID;
  Filler filler;//fills an Data with numbers
};
```

Comment: Apart from anything else your lambda has a default capture by reference meaning the values of `param` and `threadID` used aren't necessarily the ones intended.  You really need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your lambda captures a local variable `param` by reference. By the time the lambda gets to actually run, that variable may already have been destroyed. The lambda's attempt to use the now-dangling reference then exhibits undefined behavior.